# Connecting to EqualLogic with Starwind Starport Initiator, login trouble?

Tags: iscsi, dell-equallogic, starwind

We have a working iSCSI SAN, an Equallogic, which runs fine with the Microsoft iSCSI initiator.

With the Starport Initiator, we can't even connect. There's no login needed, neither local nor LDAP.

Any ideas?

The log is swamped with these:

```
6/13 17:51:37.842 CMainFrame::PoolingServiceEvents: Event checking failed, status == 2
```

Here's the relevant bits of the log:

```
6/13 17:51:29.699 CWPPiSCSITargetSelection::CreateDevice: Trying to add an iSCSI device using TargetName=iqn.2001-05.com.equallogic:8-cb2b76-315e1f15a-6d0002638444fd5f-spim1-1, IP:0xA060101, Port:3260
6/13 17:51:29.699 >> CStarPortAPI::CStarPortAPI()
6/13 17:51:29.699 >> CStarPortAPI::DriverOpen()
6/13 17:51:29.699 >> CStarPortAPI::DriverVersion(...)
6/13 17:51:29.699 CStarPortAPI::DriverVersion: Calling STARPORT_IOCTL_GET_VERSION
6/13 17:51:29.699 CStarPortAPI::DriverVersion: Calling DeviceIoControl(...)
6/13 17:51:29.699 CStarPortAPI::DriverVersion: Input: ApiVersion = 30001
6/13 17:51:29.699 CStarPortAPI::DriverVersion: Output: Version = 20110316, API = 30001, DriverOpenContext = 0, DriverInstance = FFFFFA8005844B90 
6/13 17:51:29.699 CStarPortAPI::CStarPortAPI: StarWind iSCSI Initiator version: 20091223; StariSCSI driver: API v30001, Build 0x20110316
6/13 17:51:29.699 >> CStarPortDoc::CreateiSCSIDevice(IP=0x26E6CE0, Port=3260, TargetName=iqn.2001-05.com.equallogic:8-cb2b76-315e1f15a-6d0002638444fd5f-spim1-1, Flags=0)
6/13 17:51:29.699 >> CStarPortAPI::InsertiSCSIDevice(dwIPAddress=0xA060101, dwPort=3260, szInitiaotrName=iqn.2003-06.com.starwindsoftware.starport:optiplex960, szTargetName=iqn.2001-05.com.equallogic:8-cb2b76-315e1f15a-6d0002638444fd5f-spim1-1, szAdditionalParameter=, nTargetID=...)
6/13 17:51:29.699 CStarPortAPI::InsertiSCSIDevice: Calling STARPORT_IOCTL_TARGET_MOUNT
6/13 17:51:29.699 CStarPortAPI::InsertiSCSIDevice: Input buffer:
6/13 17:51:29.699 CStarPortAPI::InsertiSCSIDevice: Flags = 0
6/13 17:51:29.699 CStarPortAPI::InsertiSCSIDevice: ServerAddress = #iscsi:10.6.1.1:3260
6/13 17:51:29.699 CStarPortAPI::InsertiSCSIDevice: Parameter[0] = InitiatorName=iqn.2003-06.com.starwindsoftware.starport:optiplex960
6/13 17:51:29.699 CStarPortAPI::InsertiSCSIDevice: Parameter[1] = TargetName=iqn.2001-05.com.equallogic:8-cb2b76-315e1f15a-6d0002638444fd5f-spim1-1
```

and then of course

```
6/13 17:51:38.731 CStarPortAPI::InsertiSCSIDevice: Session failed, status == 1326 !
6/13 17:51:38.731 >> CStarPortAPI::~CStarPortAPI()
6/13 17:51:38.731 CWPPiSCSITargetSelection::CreateDevice: Exception caught: Logon to the server failed.
6/13 17:51:38.731 CWPPiSCSITargetSelection::CreateDevice: Failed to connect to create iSCSI device using TargetName=iqn.2001-05.com.equallogic:8-cb2b76-315e1f15a-6d0002638444fd5f-spim1-1, IP:0xA060101, Port:3260
6/13 17:51:38.731 CWPPiSCSITargetSelection::CreateDevice: Creation of the iSCSI device failed with all the addresses supplied by the server.
6/13 17:51:38.731 CWPPiSCSITargetSelection::CreateDevice: Exception caught: Creation of the iSCSI device failed with all the addresses supplied by the server.
```

Comment: Stupid question, but have you asked either Dell or Starwind what they make of the event logs?

Comment: Dell can't help because nothing shows in the EqualLogic logs, and Starwind insists it's a handshake problem on the Dell side...

Comment: I suspect this is the key to the Initiator's problem: "Creation of the iSCSI device failed with all the addresses supplied by the server."

Comment: Should we shorten/change the target names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out we DO have some kind of login/password set in the eQuallogic setup... but only the Starwind client seems to pickup on it...

Answer (score 1):

Is your initiator with name IQN 
`iqn.2003-06.com.starwindsoftware.starport:optiplex960`
actually mapped/zoned to access the LUNs at target IQN `iqn.2001-05.com.equallogic:8-cb2b76-315e1f15a-6d0002638444fd5f-spim1-1` on that target?

Comment: The Starwind IQN is generated by the Starwind Initiator itself. Can I check/force it anywhere?

Comment: Sure, your Equallogic box should have a mapping/zoning configuration setup.